# vagrant lamp box authentication failure when "booting up"

Tags: php, vagrant, lamp

I'm new to vagrant and followed along with the getting started tutorial and was able to initialize and run the precise32 box and serve a "hello world" index.html file from http://127.0.0.1:8080.

However, I want to run a PHP box so I grabbed the most popular [LAMP box](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=lamp) (scotch/box) off the vagrant cloud.

My problem is that when I run the setup command for the LAMP box:

`vagrant init scotch/box; vagrant up --provider virtualbox`

The box does not appear to boot up and instead I receive the following message:

`Authentication failure. Retrying...`

I have a brand new Virtual Box install (5.0.6) am on OSX (Yosemite) and I'm not trying to do anything out of the ordinary, just run a PHP machine. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Turn on the GUI (in the Vagrantfile).  Then you can see what is happening in the box. config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.gui = true
end https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for that, but I did that straight away (after some research) and all the GUI showed me was a login prompt. Why would I need to open a separate gui to enter credentials rather than just enter them on the original terminal window? seems very odd to me.

Comment: Correction: GUI outputs a bunch of stuff then hangs on "Waiting for network configuration... Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration..." Really not sure what that's about.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why several of the most popular boxes would not work for me... but for anyone else who comes across this, I just tried several boxes until I found one that actually worked as advertised (at least with my configuration). The box that worked for me was: [smallhadroncollider/centos-6.5-lamp](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/smallhadroncollider/boxes/centos-6.5-lamp)

Here are the full steps I took to create a working PHP environment using vagrant:

1. Install VirtualBox
2. Install Vagrant
3. Add a new vagrant box: `vagrant box add smallhadroncollider/centos-6.5-lamp`
4. Create new empty directory and navigate to it within terminal... once there, initialize your new vagrant box: `vagrant init smallhadroncollider/centos-6.5-lamp`
5. Edit the auto-generated vagrant file which was created in the directory where you just ran the `vagrant init` command and comment-in the "forwarded_port" setting to allow host machine port 8080 (or whatever port you choose) to route to virtual server port 80.
6. Start-up your new vagrant box: vagrant up --provider virtualbox
7. Create `index.php` file in the same directory as your vagrant file. Run it from http://127.0.0.1:8080 and it should process your PHP code
8. Now, enable debugging messages by SSHing into your new vagrant box with `vagrant ssh`
9. Enable debug output by editing php.ini on your vagrant machine (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini) - if necessary, find where php.ini is stored using the `phpinfo()` function in your `index.php` file
10. While still on vagrant machine, restart Apache `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. Ignore the "could not reliably determine... warning message."
11. `exit` vagrant box to return to your local machine. You're done and your PHP code should now be running with debug messages.

Comment: another interesting source is http://www.puphpet.com, you can configure versions and soft to be installed, and yes it does work